# function to generate and display N random numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: java, function, random

I have to generate randoms numbers, i have a code running and working, but it doesnt seems random, it generates sequences, is right anyway? or is there another way to do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero N");
    int n = teclado.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

        double d = numerosAleatorios(i,n);
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}

public static double numerosAleatorios(double b, double c){

     return  b / c;
}
```

Comment: Use `Math.random()`

Comment: [Java Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Comment: What would you expect to be random about dividing a sequence of integers by the same integer?

Comment: im learning, im not expecting nothing, this was the first idea i came up, i dont know if using Math.Random works because i need to do it with a function

Comment: `System.out.println(new Random().nextInt((1 - 0) + 1) + 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.random() returns a pseudorandom double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero N");
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        double d = Math.random();
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Ingrese el numero N

8

```
0.660560867388863

0.6664125435482811

0.4814731375341803

0.040360135942367203

0.5503428291806611

0.25928232439131915

0.8536945699105207

0.41418876402957383
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not random because the variable i increases 1 by 1 and is divided by a constant (N) hence for each N it will display the same output I would recommend changing the code to be independant of such variables for true randomness